# Unable to update Maven configuration Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

From inside eclipse when i am doing Maven -> Update Project i am getting following issue

> Unable to update Maven configuration Could not calculate build plan:
>   Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
>   Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of
>   its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
>   Could not calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Could not
>   calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Could not
>   calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Could not
>   calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Could not
>   calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Could not
>   calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Could not
>   calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Could not
>   calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Could not
>   calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.7 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.7 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.7 Could not
>   calculate build plan: Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5 Plugin
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
>   for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5

[image]

I tried the solution provided here [Could not calculate build plan :artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 is not available in the local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378279/could-not-calculate-build-plan-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resource)

and updated my Maven project but still i am getting same issue even i tried to add dependcy in pom.xml file but did not got any success to resolve the issue.
Even i manually copied jar inside `.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-resources-plugin\2.5`

But still i am getting same issue.

Comment: Try by deleting the whole `.m2\repository\org\apache\maven`, sometimes you just download a corrupt artifact.

Comment: Thanks the above solution worked but now i am getting Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:

Comment: Did you change the Eclipse settings to point to an outside Maven installation? If so, try to force the `maven-jar-plugin` version to the latest, like I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29308838/3127111) (look at the `<build>` section of my POM, you can leave the `<configuration>` and `<executions>` parts off).

Comment: Yes i changes the eclipse settings but not sure if i can change pom.xml because its working fine for other developers only i am getting this issue

Answer (score 0):

I used the following approach to resolve it:

1. Check `settings.xml` is there `C:\Users\<<your user account>>\.m2` this location if not
2. create `settings.xml` with  the below content:

   ```
   <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                         https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
     <localRepository/>
     <interactiveMode/>
     <usePluginRegistry/>
     <offline/>
     <pluginGroups/>
     <servers/>
     <mirrors/>
     <proxies>
        <proxy>
         <id>optional</id>
         <active>true</active>
         <protocol>http</protocol>
         <username>proxyuser</username>
         <password>proxypass</password>
         <host>proxyserver.company.com</host>
         <port>8080</port>
         <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
       </proxy>
       <proxy>
         <id>optional</id>
         <active>true</active>
         <protocol>https</protocol>
         <username>proxyuser</username>
         <password>proxypass</password>
         <host>proxyserver.company.com</host>
         <port>8080</port>
         <nonProxyHosts>localhost</nonProxyHosts>
       </proxy>
     </proxies>
     <profiles/>
     <activeProfiles/>
   </settings>
   ```
3. Save the `settings.xml` file under local `C:\Users\<<your user account>>\.m2`
4. Then Right click project maven in eclipse and select "Update Project".

Answer (score 0):

I use intellij and It cost me the whole day to figure out it is because jre/JDK 7 not support https , I have jre7,jdk8,jdk4 installed on windows10. After changing my JAVA_HOME point to jdk14.It is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Verify if your connection to the net has proxy.
You have go to Internet Properties -> LAN Settings. And if you have enabled your Proxy Server, try make a setting.xml in your folder .m2. There is a example in
https://maven.apache.org/settings.html